# Install loop Android 4.4.2 Galaxy Core II

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, installation

Yesterday I recieved an update for my Samsung Galaxy Core II(SM-G355HN). I downloaded the update and tried to install it. At about 94% I received an `error code [6] in cache/fota/update.zip`. I tried to do a hard reset, but I can't get into recovery mode. When the installation fails, my phone will reboot twice, once with just the screen that says `Samsung Galaxy Core II, powered by Android`. The second time it shows that as well, but then tries to install the update again, then it fails and reboots again. My phone is in a loop since last night.

I wonder whether someone knows how to fix this, because I can't use my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it. I downloaded an Android 4.4 ROM for my phone(SM-G355HN) and flashed it with Odin while my phone was is download mode.